# What is the Rust equivalent of `size_t`?

Tags: rust

In more practical terms: **What integer data type should I use for indices in a vector, length of arrays, etc?**

There are lots of discussions on this topic for pre-1.0 Rust floating around on the internet and I can't find an authoritative answer on the final decision.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That would be `usize` and `isize` (pointer-size types, unsigned and signed). The [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/numeric.html#machine-dependent-integer-types) says that the maximal size of an array is the maximum value of `isize` such that differences of positions can be calculated.

The functions of `std::Vec` use `usize` for all indices, though.

Comment: Note that on a 32 bits system, `isize` is limited to 32 bits, so this actually constrains the size of an array to 2GB even though 4GB are available. On 64 bits, I doubt it'll be an issue.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: on existing 64-bit platforms addresses are only 48 bits, so 63 bits is ample.

Comment: @MatthieuM. why is it 2GB and not 2G elements?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen It is 2G elements, which can be as little as 2GB (even though you’d have enough address space for more) when elements are byte-sized.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: I supposed, Rust having low-level capabilities, that one should always be able to compute the difference between a pointer to the first element and a pointer one-past-the-end element, even when casting those pointers to `*const u8`. Well, [let's ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324794/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-32-bits)!

Comment: This link has been removed.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I fixed the link now.