# Is there a limit to the size of a BigInt or BigUint in Rust?

Tags: rust, biginteger

Is there no limit to the size of a `BigInt` or `BigUint` from the `num` crate in Rust? I see that in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693273/is-there-an-upper-bound-to-biginteger) its length is bounded by the upper limit of an integer `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as it is stored as an array of `int`.

I did go through the documentation for it but could not really deduce my answer from

> A BigUint-typed value BigUint { data: vec!(a, b, c) } represents a
>   number (a + b * big_digit::BASE + c * big_digit::BASE^2).

`big_digit::BASE` being defined as

```
pub const BASE: DoubleBigDigit = 1 << BITS
```

`BITS` in turn is 32

So is the BigInt being represented as `(a + b * 64 + c * 64^2)` internally?

Comment: Whatever, that's a theoretical limit as I cannot see any usage of such a big number as `2^u64::MAX`

Comment: BigInt is being represented as `(a + b * 2^32 + c * (2^32)^2)`, so the limit is pretty big

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**TL;DR**: the maximum number that can be represented is roughly:

```
3.079 x 10^22212093154093428519
```

I suppose that nothing useful needs such a big number to be represented. You can be certain that the `num_bigint` will do the job, whatever the usage you have with it.

---

In theory, there is no limit to the `num` big integers size since [the documentation says nothing about it (version `0.1.44`)](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.1.44/num_bigint/struct.BigUint.html). However, there is a concrete limit that we can calculate:

[`BigUint` is a `Vec<BigDigit>`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.1.44/num_bigint/), and [`BigDigit` is an `u32`](https://docs.rs/num-bigint/0.1.44/num_bigint/big_digit/type.BigDigit.html). As far as I know, Rust does not define a max size for a `Vec`, but since [the maximum possible allocated size is `isize::MAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32334789/4498831), the maximum number of `BigDigit` aka `u32` is:

```
MAX_LEN = isize::MAX / sizeof(u32)
```

With this information, we can deduce that the maximum of a `num::BigUint` (and a `num::BigInt` as well) in the current implementation is:

```
(u32::MAX + 1) ^ MAX_LEN - 1 = 2^32^MAX_LEN - 1
```

To have this formula, we mimic the way we calculate `u8::MAX`, for example:

- `bit::MAX` is `1`,
- the length is 8,
- so the maximum is `(bit::MAX + 1) ^ 8 - 1 = 255`

---

Here is the full demonstration from the formula given by the `num` documentation:

```
a + b * big_digit::BASE + c * big_digit::BASE^2 + ...
```

If we are taking the max value, `a == b == c == u32::MAX`. Let's name it `a`. Let's name `big_digit::BASE` `b` for convenience. So the max number is:

```
sum(a * b^n) where n is from 0 to (MAX_LEN - 1)
```

if we factorize, we get:

```
a * sum(b^n) where n is from 0 to (MAX_LEN - 1)
```

[The general formula of the sum of `x^n` is `(x^(n + 1) - 1) / (x - 1)`](http://mikestoolbox.com/powersum.html). So, because `n` is `MAX_LEN - 1`, the result is:

```
a * (b^(MAX_LEN - 1 + 1) - 1) / (b - 1)
```

We replace a and b with the right value, and the biggest representable number is:

```
u32::MAX * (2^32^MAX_LEN - 1) / (2^32 - 1)
```

`u32::MAX` is `2^32 - 1`, so this can be simplified into:

```
2^32^MAX_LEN - 1
```

Comment: But what about `(a + b * big_digit::BASE + c * big_digit::BASE^2)` @Boiethios ? Does this not put a cap as per the docs?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan The documentation about a maximum is implicit: it depends on the maximum size of a `Vec`.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan nothing prevents you to use `BigUint { data: vec!(a, b, c, d) }` and get `(a + b * big_digit::BASE + c * big_digit::BASE^2 + d * big_digit::BASE^3)`. And why stop at 4 elements? The actual limit will be bound by whatever memory you have.

Comment: Actually the maximum size that can be allocated by Rust is `isize::MAX`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324794/maximum-size-of-an-array-in-32-bits

Comment: @trentcl I am not sure of what you say, but I did an error. I edited to give the full calculus, maybe I am wrong, but I think it is more accurate.